# While loop on a mysql call is throwing unknown PDO exception 'General Error'

Tags: php, while-loop

I use the following (or similar) code on hundreds of pages I have built:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    do something with data returned...


    $id = NULL;
    $name = NULL;

}
```

Out of nowwhere, I started receiving the following error on a few pages:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in C:....page.php:28 Stack trace: #0
>   C:..page.php(28): PDOStatement->fetch() #1 {main} thrown

The first loop will run (with no problem) but gives an error AFTER the first loop. The error code (line 28) references the line:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

I have never seen this before. As a test, I modified the code to store all returned results as:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->fetchALL();

foreach($rows as $row) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    do something with data returned...


    $id = NULL;
    $name = NULL;

}
```

and the system works. Any idea as to why?

Comment: what's in your 'do something' section?

Comment: @feela - Line 28 is the 'while' loop

Comment: @Marc B - running passwords through phpass code

Comment: @Marc B - thanks for making me look at the code again - I'll give an answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: After looking through 'do something' area again - I realized the database initializers ($sql) were the same in the select and an insert/update statement within the body. Changing these to unique values corrected the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Ah, didn't realise that. Oh well I guess it'll have to wait. :) +1 for the info :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless this is merely a typo in your question, your arrow operator is incomplete.

```
$stmt>execute();

// Should be
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: only an error when writing to SO, it is correct in my code - I will update here

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt>execute();
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: commented above - only an error in the SO posting not in my actual code